# Создание файла d.ts для JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, модули

Пишу npm пакет на JS. Описания методов пишу использую JSDoc. Как мне использовать файлы d.ts, чтобы при использовании моей библиотеки описания ссылались бы к этому файлу, как это например в системных объектах сделано, там же когда ищешь определения открывается файл lib.es5.d.ts.
Как мне это сделать, весь день гуглю, ничего не понимаю(((

Answer (score 0):

Создайте файл `*.d.ts` с тем же именем рядом с каждым модулем ноды...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Их нужно как то экспортировать, подключать?
Что в них писать, точно так же как написано в системных d.ts например та же lib.es5.d.ts?

Comment: @the_alex_mark Посмотрите сами, npm install --no-save @material-ui/lab
Обычные файлы объявления модулей, некий аналог .h файлов из c++

Comment: @the_alex_mark если вопрос исчерпан - отметьте ответ как верный

Comment: Трипольский Пётр  
Сделал так  
В файле `package.json` прописал: `"types": "./types.d.ts"`.  
В файле `types.d.ts` прописал вручную все классы и методы моей библиотеки.
Вручную потому что пишу её на js, соответственно ничего не компилирую и заголовочные файлы у меня не генерируются.  
Всё работает. Наконец то можно указывать перегрузки методов.  
Если интересно библиотека доступна в NPM: `npm install proglib --save`.  
На днях выложу новую версию.